# Ninject resolve all for interface type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

```
    public SelectUserQuery: IQuery{
        public string Command {
            get{ return "...."; }
        }
    }

    public class QueryDispatcher : IQueryDispatcher
    {
        //... 
        //..

        public void Dispatch<TQuery>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery
        {
            foreach (var handler in kernel.ResolveAll<IQueryHandler<TQuery>>())
            {
                handler.Handle(query);
            }
        }
    }

    public class QueryManager{

        //...

        public Activate(){
            queryDispatcher.Dispatch(new SelectUserQuery());
        }
    }
```

This is resolving types that I used `queryDispatcher.Dispatch(new SelectUserQuery());`

But I am creating a private method in QueryManager to run Dispatch operations like this:

```
public class QueryManager{

        //...

        public SeletectUser(){
            Apply(new SelectUserQuery());
        }

        private Apply(IQuery query){
            queryDispatcher.Dispatch(query);
        }
    }
```

This is not working. `kernel.ResolveAll<IQueryHandler<TQuery>>()`  is returning empty collection.

Bindings are like this:

```
public class ServiceModule: NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<IQueryHandler<SelectUserQuery>>().To<SelectUserQueryHandler>();
        Kernel.Bind<IQueryDispatcher>().To<QueryDispatcher>();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your bindings?

Comment: looks correct. Can you please verify that you're accessing the same instance of the kernel, that you don't have defined `IQueryHandler` twice, and that you're trying to do `GetAll<>` after the `IQueryHandler` has been bound?